# Citing problem in tabularx with endfloat

Tags: tabularx, endfloat, ltablex

Guys I'm hoping you can help me with this one.

I'm trying to compile a document with the apa6 class using apacite/natbibapa. 
I run in to trouble when I want to use '\citet' in the table. '\citep' and others do work!

When I use '\citet' I get this error:

Undefined control sequence \end{tabularx} (line 10)

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[man,a4paper]{apa6}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{landscape}{table}
\shorttitle{foo}
\title{foo}
\author{foo}
\affiliation{foo}
\authornote{foo}
%
\abstract{foo}
\keywords{foo,foo}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Table~\ref{tab:Characteristics}
%
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{*5{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
\caption{test} \\
\label{tab:Characteristics} \\
\hline
Study & \ Portfolio name & \ Portfolio type &  Relevant SDL outcome variables & Context \\
\hline 
\citet{Altahawi}  & - & Training portfolio &  Students' perspectives on assessment with e-portfolios & Undergraduate education (Medicine)   \\      
\hline                                                              
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
{}
\end{tablenotes}        
\end{landscape}
%
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{__review}
\end{document}
```

And the associated .bib file:

```
@article{Altahawi,
author = {Altahawi, F. and Sisk, B. and Poloskey, S. and Hicks, C. and Dannefer, E. F.},
title = {Student perspectives on assessment: Experience in a competency-based portfolio system},
journal = {Medical Teacher},
volume = {34},
number = {3},
pages = {221-225}, 
year = {2012},  
DOI = {10.3109/0142159x.2012.652243}  
}
```

Again, I suspect 'citet' is causing the problems. Also, when endfloat is not used, there are no problems.

So can anyone help me with the origin of this issue and finding the solution? 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Many thanks for posting an excellent MWE. My hunch is that the `apacite` package, when loaded with the `natbibapa` option, does something (slightly unexpected) to the `\citet` command. Oddly, no such problems occur if `\citet` is used outside a table. Anyway, using the `\citealt{...}` or `\citealp{...}` commands within the table would seem to work as well (as you report as well), and the results of doing so may look better than the result of `\citep{...}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your quick answer. I agree they might look better, although \citealt{} doesn't work here. 

I have to look into apa rules again to see if those are allowed in tables.

Comment: @Mico Actually, to comment further on what may be happening, the \citet command also works when there is just one author! 

So something happens when there are more authors, but I don't know what exactly. I should probably communicate with the creators of the packages.

For now I have solved the problem by abandoning the natbibapa option and just going with the classic apacite, no problems then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In correspondence with the author of the apacite package, he pointed me towards something in the apa6 class manual:

> 6.5.3 natbib
>   natbib Specifying the natbib option implicitly loads apacite and natbib, and directs apa6
>   to mask references using natbib commands if the mask option is specified.

So in short, the natbib option should be loaded as an option with the apa6 class. Apacite should not be loaded as a package.